# What topology goes on $L_{loc}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In his book on the Navier-Stokes problem, Lemarie-Rieusset says at multiple points that a Banach space is embedded in $L_{loc}^2$. My question is as in the title.

Comment: You typically give it the topology generated by the seminorms $\| \cdot\|_{L^2 (K_j)} $, where the $K_j $ form a nested sequence of compact sets that exhaust your original domain.

Comment: Or, in a way simplifying @Jose27's comment, the compact subsets could be quantified over _all_ compact subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual topology on $L^p_\mathrm{loc}(\Omega)$, for $\Omega$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is given by the following family of seminorms: For every compact $K\subseteq \Omega$, consider $\Vert f\Vert_{p,K}=\left(\int_K |f|^p\right)^{1/p}$.

This makes $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ a locally convex, non-normed space.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been my guess.